# Rails - how to find out user's role in the system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, roles

I have following models:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
  ...
end
```

I am trying to find out user's role, but when I try to

```
user.assignments.name
```

It doesn't print out the user's role from the table **roles** (column name).

How to print out that?

Comment: I have many roles, how to find out my role in the system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map on your association in order to get a specific field:

```
user.roles.map(&:name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, when I try this, I get just `undefined method 'name' for #<Assignment:0x007f946d956650>`

Comment: In more recent versions of Rails, I recommend [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) for this kind of expression: `user.roles.pluck(:name)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`user.roles.each {|role| puts role }`

You can't call `name` method on `user.assignments` because it's an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
user.assignments.each do |a|
  puts a.name
end
```